# Error when setting button inside recycler view?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I get error when I press button inside recycler view. My application is not crashing. I am trying to set a button in the recycler view and calling`setOnClickListener` inside `onBindViewHolder`. Inside the `holder.Button.setOnClickListener{}`I change the button text to `notified`. But when I press a button the values of other button text in another list   also changes. This is a listview of firestore documents. I have many documents that are uploaded into the recycler view. If I am getting the error how should I implement the button onclicklistener without this error.[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Oxm.jpg][1]][1] [![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
/**This my activity for recycler view*/

package com.example.bloodbankcompany.recyclerview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Adapter
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.MyAdapter
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.R
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.User1
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.User2
import com.google.firebase.firestore.*
import java.lang.NullPointerException

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var userArrayList: ArrayList<User2>
    private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter2
    private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        userArrayList= arrayListOf()
        myAdapter =MyAdapter2(userArrayList)


        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter

        EventChangeListener()



    }



    private fun EventChangeListener() {
         try {
             mFireStore.collection("applicationForm").addSnapshotListener(object :
                 EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
                 override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                     if (error != null) {
                         Log.e("firestore error", error.message.toString())
                     }
                 try {
                     for (dc: DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {
                         if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                             userArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(User2::class.java))
                         }
//                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,userArrayList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                     }
                 } catch (e:NullPointerException){

                 }
                     myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                 }

             })
         } catch (e:NullPointerException){

         }


    }


}
```

````
/**
* This is my myAdapter  activity for adapater*/


 package com.example.bloodbankcompany.recyclerview


import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.R
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.RegisterActivity
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.User2
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_item2.view.*

class MyAdapter2(private val userList: ArrayList<User2>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder>(){
var id: String = ""
    private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item2,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)



    }

  

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val user:User2 = userList[position]
        holder.name.text= user.name
        holder.phone.text= user.phone
        holder.address.text =user.address
        holder.bloodGroup.text= user.bloodgroup
        holder.id.text = user.id

//Setting onclicklistener to my adapter and starting intent
        holder.button.setOnClickListener {
//            holder.io = "kkj"
//            holder.id.text = " "
            holder.button.setText("notified")


//            val context=holder.button.context
//            val intent = Intent( context, RegisterActivity::class.java)
//            context.startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size

    }

    public class MyViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){




        val name : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvfirstname1)
        val phone :TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvphone11)
        val address : TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvaddress1)
        val bloodGroup: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvbloodg1)
        val id: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvid)
        var io: String? = ""
        var button: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_notify)

        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
            init {
                itemView.btn_notify.setOnClickListener {

                }
            }


        }




    }
} ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Oxm.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqDMf.jpg
````

Answer (score 2):

create interface for `clickListener` in your adapter and set it in `constructor`

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
fun onItemClick(position: Int)
}
```

and in `ViewHolder` set `bind` your button

```
fun bind(position: Int, listener: OnItemClickListener) {
button.setOnClickListener { v -> listener.onItemClick(position) }
}
```

and then set this code in `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.bind( position , onItemClickListener)
```

finally when click on button you can action in `Activity or Fragment`

example :

```
adapter = Adapter(getContext(), models) { position -> }
```

Comment: Getting error when typing `holder.bind( position , onItemClickListener)` for ` onItemClickListener` and also for `adapter` code

Comment: set onItemClickListenert in constructor

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple Code, Without using Interface

Actually what I found is you were doing it the correct way, but you were using two `ViewHolder` classes there which is the cause of issue. Try to use the below code once and try again. Hope it works.

```kotlin
class mAdapter(val context: Context, private val dataList: ArrayList<String>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<mAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): mAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_card_view, parent, false)
        return mAdapter.ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: mAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txtView.setText(dataList.get(position))
        
        //Your Button setOnClickLister
        holder.btnName.setOnClickListener {
            
            // action here
        
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

       
        val txtView  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
        val btnName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnName) as Button

    }

}
```

Comment: Still the error happens. When I press the button  , Other buttons text also changes to notified